# What is the type of function that I'm biding and passing down as props in React with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created a custom `Checkbox` component.

TypeScript in the project does not accept `any` types, so I need to indicate the exact type of `handleCheckbox()` function (located in `FilterBox` component) that I am passing down as props to child component `Checkbox`.

```
const handleCheckbox = (state: Record<string, unknown>) => {
    const _preProcessNewState = { ...globalStatus, ...state };
    //Change the States
    setGlobalStatus(_preProcessNewState);
  };
```

Below we pass this function to Checkbox:

```
<Checkbox
                text={t(TranslationConstants.Map.asapOrderInFilter)}
                property={t(TranslationConstants.Map.checkboxAsapProperty)}
                checked={globalStatus['asap']}
                fn={handleCheckbox.bind(this)}
              />
```

Now, in Checkbox component I need to declare the correct type for fn():

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

type checkboxProps = {
  text: string;
  checked: boolean;
  fn: (e: any) => void;
  property: string;
};

const CheckBox = (props: checkboxProps) => {
  const { text, checked, fn, property } = props;
  const [statusCheck, setStatusCheck] = useState(checked);

  const handleChange = () => {
    const _newState = !statusCheck;
    setStatusCheck(_newState);
    fn({ [property]: _newState });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setStatusCheck(checked);
  }, [checked]);

  return (
    <div>
      {' '}
      <label>
        {' '}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={statusCheck}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />{' '}
        {text}
      </label>{' '}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckBox;
```

I've tried HTMLInputElement, React.HTMLInputElement. Didn't work.

Here is a full code if you need more context: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-gould-d4bry?file=/src/App.tsx

Along with it I also need to fix any types in OrderList.
All builds break if there is type any so it is crucial to declare correct types.

Comment: "_Along with it I also need to fix any types in OrderList_": I do not see any reference to `OrderList` in the code you share in the question? Do you mean it is unrelated to the function typing issue? In that case, you should make it a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I didn't want to pollute SO with redundant posts since other any types are in the same code I'm sharing in Codesandbox here in this post. If you want it to be separate post, I can do it. Would you click the link to Sandbox to see what occurrences of any type I'm talking about? I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: "_other `any` types are in the same code I'm sharing in Codesandbox_": while you have put them in the same project, they require a different explanation and solution, hence they require a different question (potentially several of them). Make sure first that the current question is solved, then proceed with next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to indicate the exact type of handleCheckbox() function (located in FilterBox component) that I'm passing down as props to child component Checkbox

I guess you rather mean that you need to improve the `checkboxProps["fn"]` definition (which is the prop that you pass `handleCheckbox` to), in order to avoid the usage of `any`:

```
type checkboxProps = {
  text: string;
  checked: boolean;
  fn: (e: any) => void;
  // It throws warning here. Here is where I need to indicate type for e: and returning value (not sure if it's void)

  property: string;
};
```

> I've tried HTMLInputElement, React.HTMLInputElement

That *could* have been in the right track, should that `fn` prop function be called directly as an event listener of your `<input>`.

But you have a `handleChange` function in between, which calls your `fn` in a different way than a simple event listener:

```
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={statusCheck}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
```

```
  const handleChange = () => {
    const _newState = !statusCheck;
    setStatusCheck(_newState);
    fn({ [property]: _newState });
  };
```

That `handleChange` function does not use your event argument, so there is really no need to look for such event type.

It calls your `fn` prop function with 1 argument `{ [property]: _newState }`, which is of type `Record<string, boolean>`.

So you can define your `fn` prop as: `fn: (newState: Record<string, boolean>) => void;`

It might also be possible to further define the type, to indicate that it has a single member, defined by the `property` prop string, but that would involve generics in several places.

On the other hand, it seems to me that your `checkboxProps` type is more complex than it could be: you are passing down a property name, which is solely used to build an ad hoc object to be passed to your `fn` prop callback. In that case, it would be simpler to pass it directly the bare new checked value, and let the callback handle its object and property name, which is known by the parent component (`FilterBox` in your case). That way, you avoid having to pass down the `property` string, and break this strong coupling between `FilterBox` and `Checkbox`: now your `Checkbox` component can be used with other parent components, which may not use any object state.

```
type checkboxProps = {
  text: string;
  checked: boolean;
  fn: (newIsChecked: boolean) => void;
};

// In Checkbox component
  const handleChange = () => {
    const _newState = !statusCheck;
    setStatusCheck(_newState);
    fn(_newState);
  };

// In FilterBox component (or any other parent component)
<Checkbox
  text={t(TranslationConstants.Map.asapOrderInFilter)}
  checked={globalStatus['asap']}
  fn={(newIsChecked) => {
    handleCheckbox({
      asap: newIsChecked
    });
  }}
/>
```

Then if you want to avoid having to manually build the callback when you use the `<Checkbox>` component many times with different property names, you could make a generating function, for example in the lines of:

```
function makeHandleCheckboxFnForProperty(propertyName: string) {
  return (newIsChecked: boolean) => {
    handleCheckbox({
      [propertyName]: newIsChecked
    });
  }
}
```

and then in your template:

```
<Checkbox
  text={t(TranslationConstants.Map.asapOrderInFilter)}
  checked={globalStatus['asap']}
  fn={makeHandleCheckboxFnForProperty('asap')}
/>
```